# How to change the clang verion when compiling AzerothCore with dashboard setup

Tags: azerothcore

I'm trying to compile [AzerothCore](https://github.com/azerothcore/azerothcore-wotlk) using the [dashboard setup](https://www.azerothcore.org/wiki/ac-dashboard-core-installation) on Debian, so I normally compile with:

```
./acore.sh compiler build
```

However, my default `clang` version is 7 and it no longer works with AzerothCore as I need `clang-10` or higher.

So I've installed `clang-11` and the following works:

```
clang-11 --version
```

But when I try to compile, it still uses clang 7 and fails.

How do I change the clang version when compiling AzerothCore?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open the `conf/config.sh` file (if you don't have it, copy it from `conf/dist/config.sh` to `conf/config.sh`) and change:

```
CCOMPILERC="/usr/bin/clang"
CCOMPILERCXX="/usr/bin/clang++"
```

with:

```
CCOMPILERC="/usr/bin/clang-11"
CCOMPILERCXX="/usr/bin/clang++-11"
```